# How to clean a column in a specific time in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

My focus is to clean a specific column in a specific sheet every one hours.

I wrote this code but doesn't work.

```
Sub CleanColumn()
   Worksheets("Calculation").Columns(2).ClearContents
   Call test
End Sub
Sub test()
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("01:00:00"), "CleanColumn"
End Sub
```

Where I wronge?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this could only be achieved when the file is open. Are you considering this?

Comment: Are you getting an error?  If so what error and on which line?

Comment: Thank you for all comments. 
Calculation is a specific sheet. 
Yes, It has to work when the files is open. 
No, I don't have any type of error.

Comment: Is always in the same file, but I didn't write the code in its sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cI got it to work by copying your code to Module1 in a workbook and changing to this:

```
Sub test()
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("01:00:o0"), "Module1.CleanColumn"
End Sub
```

I believe that you need to tell it where the subroutine CleanColumn resides
Since it is on the hour, you should explicitly define which workbook and which worksheet like:

```
Workbook("\\f2\folder\wb_time.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns(2).ClearContents
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort .

Answer (score 2):

below code is working.

```
Public Const ClCol = "CleanColumn"


Sub CleanColumn()
  'Change the range as per your req..
   Sheet1.Range("A1").ClearContents
   Call test
End Sub


Sub test()
'Once you change the below time it will be adjusted accordingly.
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:01:00"), ClCol

End Sub
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort.